# My codes won't stop looping (Ionic React Firestore) (ReactJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, loops, google-cloud-firestore

I have this list of codes that calls data from Firestore.

```
db.collection('CLASS').where('class_teacher', '==', teachername).get().then(snap => {snap.forEach(doc => {
    setData([...data, {
      studentname: String(doc.data().class_student),
      instrument: String(doc.data().instrument),
      grade: String(doc.data().musical_grade),
      day: String(doc.data().day),
      time: String(doc.data().time),
    }]);
    console.log(doc.id);
  })
})
```

and when I run the codes, the program won't stop printing cards. It seems like it loops over and over again.

I tried with `useEffect` too, but it won't make my program print the cards. Can anybody help?

Comment: when I run the codes, the program won't stop printing cards, it seems like it loops over and over again. I tried with useEffect too, but it won't make my program print the cards. Can anybody help?

Comment: can you show some more code than just the setData. something is triggering the loop

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more code? specially the useEffect?

I see you calling setData inside your loop.
I will assume you have something like

```
const [data, setData] = useState()
useEffect(()=>{
//your code here
},[data]) // --> make this is an empty array '[]' instead of '[data]'
```

If you have **data** in the dependency array of the useEffect, it'll keep looping since it's changed by **setData** continuously. it should be replaced by an empty array

Also, another thing to try is to put a log exactly before the first line in your code snippet. That will make it easier to detect whether the infinite loop is going over the query, or the query results

Comment: ```const [data, setData] = useState([{
    studentname: '',
    instrument: '',
    grade: '',
    day: '',
    time: '',
    id: '',
    pic: ''
  }]);```

i only have this for the data

for the useEffect, yep I didn't put anything in [], I just let it empty, but it still wont stop printing. I hope this info helps

Comment: May I suggest you put a console.log line before the db query, and comment out the setData and check the results?



console.log("Before DB Query")
db.collection('CLASS').where('class_teacher', '==', teachername).get().then(snap => {snap.forEach(doc => {
    console.log("Doc id:",doc.id);
  })
})

It'd help to know whether the whole query is the one being called frequently.